# How can i get my spinner value when i use Calendar

Tags: android

I use spinner to show date on Calendar class.

I can get the year and month,but i can't get day's value on `spinner`.

It shows

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

How can i fix the issue?

Here is the code:

```
private void datePick(){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            dataYear.add("" + (calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - i));
        }

        adapterSpYear = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner, dataYear);
        adapterSpYear.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spYear.setAdapter(adapterSpYear);
        spYear.setSelection(34);//for 1982

        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            dataMonth.add("" + (i < 10 ? "0" + i : i));
        }

        adapterSpMonth = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner, dataMonth);
        adapterSpMonth.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spMonth.setAdapter(adapterSpMonth);


        adapterSpDay = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner, dataDay);
        adapterSpDay.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spDay.setAdapter(adapterSpDay);

        spMonth.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
                dataDay.clear();
                Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.valueOf(spYear.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, arg2);
                int dayOfMonth = calendar1.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                for (int i = 1; i <= dayOfMonth; i++) {
                    dataDay.add("" + (i < 10 ? "0" + i : i));
                }
                adapterSpDay.notifyDataSetChanged();


                String year=spYear.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String month=spMonth.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String day=spDay.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Log.i("test",".>>>>Year>>>>"+year);
                Log.i("test",".>>>>Month>>>>"+month);
                Log.i("test",".>>>>Day>>>>"+day);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0pKs.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njmss.png)

Comment: I think that you should use adapterSpDay.clear() and adapterSpDay.add or addAll to make changes in it instead of clearing and adding new data to your dataDay array

Comment: Check value of spDay.getSelectedItem(). It is null as you not select any day, you only selected year and month..

Comment: If i set the code String day=spDay.getSelectedItem().toString();
Start the app it will crash immediately.
I got the solution from Sangeet, thanks for your help @SHIVANIGARG and Beyka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spinner Adapter  `adapterSpDay.notifyDataSetChanged();`will not refresh the adapter data. You have to create adapter and set adapter for day again inside

```
   spMonth.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int arg2, long arg3) 
             {  // Here create adapter for day again by passing new data and set that adapter to day spinner.
                ............
                      }
```

Comment: thank you @Sangeet Suresh, i fix the issue now. The problem is day adapter place.